# Link a button on a site to specific view

Tags: xcode, view, storyboard

I have created two views in my main storyboard ->

[image]

Now I added a button on the first one which should link to the other one (so when I press it it should lead to the other view). I have id't the one I want to link to with SceneViewController.

I copied the following code (and defined the method in the header) ->

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

SceneViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SceneViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

But nothing happens when I press the button. Anybody a clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, cheers!

Comment: have you looked into using segues?

Comment: I already linked the method by the way. So that shouldn't be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to just copy the IBAction code. You have to link the button in the storyboard to the IBAction method you created in your header file.

Open your storyboard, click on the Assistant Editor icon at top right of screen (little icon of a waistcoat and bow tie). Make sure the right pane has your header file selected, if not you can chane to it in the drop down at the top.

Then zoom in on your button, right click on it and drag to the IBAction line in your header file. This should create the connection for you.

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint on the method? Is it getting that far or not calling the method at all?